# Add Typescript type to props

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I wonder how I can declare that the param `...props` inside my function declaration are of type `BaseViewProps` in the following notation:

```
export interface BaseViewProps extends ScrollViewProps {
}

/**
 * Underlying layout for all screens
 */
export function BaseView({ children, ...props }) {
  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.mainContainer}>
      <ScrollView
        contentContainerStyle={styles.scrollContainer}
        {...props}
      >
        <AppHeader/>
        {children}
      </ScrollView>
    </SafeAreaView>
  )
}
```

I have tried something like this:

```
export function BaseView({ children, ...props} = { any, BaseViewProps})
```

But then I get an error `'any' refers to a type but is used as a value here`.

Comment: what did you intend to?

Comment: Well basically get proper typing for my props

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
export function BaseView({ children, ...props}: : { children: any, [key: string]: BaseViewProps })
```

`=` is used for default value, not type

Comment: I get `TS2339: Property 'children' does not exist on type '{ any: any; BaseViewProps: any; }'.`

Comment: I updated the question, but know I see desgin flows in your code architecture (or maybe React architecture). Why would pass object like { children: [1, 2, 3, 4], name: 'test', key: 1, .. }? Or I don't understand something.